What happened with CIFS / SAMBA connections on Kernel 5.15.0-102-generic?
While I can 'ls' and 'mount' SMB/CIFS shares I can't in turn mount those directories to docker containers, it leads to:
Error: statfs /mnt/images: resource temporarily unavailable
exit code: 125

Which I can also replicate without trying to start a container by invoking statfs directly:
$ statfs /mnt/images
statfs syscall returned error: resource temporarily unavailable

This started after a reboot moving me to Kernel 5.15.0-102-generic on LTS Ubunutu 22.04.

In troubleshooting this I found that a regression to the Linux kernel had caused this issue:
https://lore.kernel.org/all/Zb5eL-AKcZpmvYSl@eldamar.lan/T/
And this regression has obviously moved in to the 5.15.0-102-generic version. This has been fixed upstream already so it's either wait for a new kernel version or downgrade to an older one if you need this functionality now.
This is how I reverted to my previous kernel and solved my issue:
https://askubuntu.com/a/1393019/1782144
